# ARC doesn't release instance variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a problem with ARC. After few hours of debugging I gave up and decided to check here.

Basically I have a `MainViewController`, which creates instance of `PreviewsView`.

In `PreviewsView` I have delegate and dataSource properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet id<PreviewsDataSource> dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet id<PreviewsDelegate> delegate;
```

I create instance of `PreviewsView` in `MainViewController`, set `self` as `delegate` and `dataSource`, add it to view and save as an instance variable:

```
- (void)addPreviews {
    previewsView = [[PreviewsView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 75, 1024, 480)];
    previewsView.dataSource = self;
    previewsView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:previewsView];
}
```

Then when I remove `MainViewController` from navigation controller ACR deallocates is, BUT `previewsView` is still exist (WHY???) and actually running the method which triggers `[self.delegate doSomeStuff]`. As `MainViewController` already deallocates - it throws **`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`**.

So basically:

- Instance of `MainViewController` owns instance of `PreviewsView` (previewsView)
- Instance of `MainViewController` assigned as `delegate` and `dataSource` in `PreviewsView`
- After deallocation instance of `MainViewController`, previewsView is still alive and running.

Any ideas why??
Thanks.

Comment: Is it intentional that you create a view named `previewsView` (in the `addPreviews` method), but add a completely different subview (`previewsCaroucel`)?

Comment: sorry, it's due to renaming variables before posting here

Answer (score 2):

you need to set your delegates to nil, before releasing MainViewController like so
    previewsView.delegate = nil;
    previewsView.dataSource = nil;

Preferable call this code in dealloc method of you MainViewController -> you still can use it also with ARC like this

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    previewsView.dataSource = nil;
    previewsView.delegate = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

You should keep in mind that the protocols !assumes! your instance of previewsView is still "alive" ( notifications works the same way ) and try to send messages to your instance whether it's dead or alive . So when MainViewController is realeased, also previewsView is, but the delegates are still "alive". Therefore you need to undelegate them by setting them to nil;)

Answer (score 1):

unsafe_unretained does not nil an ivar. __weak does.

Does the MainViewController member `previewsView` retain it? In viewDidUnload or after you have finished with previewsView, set it to nil, ie: `previewsView = nil`.

Generally all IBOutlets or subviews held as ivars should be __weak. If you don't need the previewsView after adding it as a subview you can remove the ivar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: AFAIK `weak` isn't available in iOS 4.x, so that isn't solution for me.

Comment: In that cause you must explicitly nil your member, or not retain it.

Comment: How nil will help in that case? Nil won't release previewsView, previewsView will still have reference to released MainViewController.

Comment: "Don't retain" won't work. I need to save it as an instance variable.

Comment: Pre-ARC you would do this in dealloc

`object.delegate = nil;`
`object.source = nil;`
`object = nil;`

Comment: that was more recommendation. I never did that in my dealloc methods. [object release] always worked. And I didn't have EXC_BAD_ACCESS because of that.

Comment: Anyway, I've tried to do what you offered: I've added `previewsView.delegate` and `previewsView.dataSource` to `MainViewController`'s `viewDidUnload` - no effect

Comment: `viewDidUnload` will usually only be called in low-memory situations, not always when the view controller is deallocated. You can still implement `dealloc` in ARC for your own cleanup code (just don't call `[super dealloc]`).